# what is the standard of query writing in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I have confused for query writing in `CodeIgniter`.
Where should write a query in `model` or `controller`? I want to know international standard of query writing in `CodeIgniter` or what would be best practice for me?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have ever read about `MVC architecture` you would never ask this question. The name itself will tell you. `M-model`, where you write all your database related methods, `C-controller` where you write all your business logic and finally `view` which lets you show the desired view to the end user.

Coming to your question about `Query`, it is always recommended to write it in the `model`. There is no international standard or something. You can follow whichever suits your application. The `CodeIgniter` built-in `query builder` class is always recommended as `CodeIgniter` will handle all possible `SQL Injections` and attacks to the `database`. I personally suggest you use `CodeIgniter` query builder class. I've been using CodeIgniter more than 2 years from now.

If you have any doubts or reference, you can refer [Codeigniter docs](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/index.html) for the database. One of the best-documented framework I have ever seen.

Comment: well but I've seen some of people write query in controller on laravel that's why have confused what should to do actually what would be best practice i know MVC architecture suggest for model

Comment: I don't have much knowledge about LARAVEL. It's all their convenience how they write queries in the controller. But I strongly recommend you to write it in the model as it's easy to trace the issues with queries and query results.

Comment: You are welcome. If you found my answer worthy, please accept and upvote.

Comment: In laravel you also write queries in model. I can't think of a reason to do them in a controller.